# Interarrival times of Negative Binomial (Yule-Furry) process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-process

The interarrival (ia) times of a Poisson process are exponentially distributed. What distribution function describes the ia times of a Negative Binomial process aka Yule-Furry process?

Thanks!

Comment: It may depend on how you define the arrivals.  The negative binomial refers to events being the time when a success occurs after say k consecutive failures, but k can be any particular numbers and the k failures do not need to be consecutive.  There seems to be a lot to specify and I think the waiting time may depend on the specification of the point process.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. It seems that the distribution which describes the interarrival times is a Pareto distribution. As you well indicated (thanks again), the definition of the arrivals impinges on the resulting form of the Pareto.